# hook - update entry of my extension

Tags: typo3

I need your help. I created my extension. I can add entries in backend. I have follow hook:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass']['fefiles'] =
    \Istar\Fefiles\Hooks\DataHandler::class;
```

My Data Handler file:

```
class DataHandler{

    public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations(
        $status,
        $table,
        $recordUid,
        array $fields,
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject
    ) {
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/666.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
        fclose($fp);
    }


    public function processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(&$fieldArray, $table, $id, $parentObject)
    {
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/666.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
        fclose($fp);
    }


    public function processCmdmap_preProcess($command, &$table, $id, $value, $parentObject)
    {
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/666.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
        fclose($fp);
    }



}
```

I want to receive data about updated entry.(uid and other).
But when I update entry it nothing happens. I try to create file in my code, as you can see. I doing it to test it and receive data. Nothing happens. The file was created when I add code for create file to method __construct.

I hope you understand my problem. Someone, help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hook into `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations` and `processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray` you have to register, as the prefix of the names suggest (`processDatamap_*`), your class to:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][]
```

instead of

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass'][]
```

**Update:**
It would probably look something like this. Registering them to both cases to get all the hooks:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = \Istar\Fefiles\Hooks\DataHandler::class;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass'][] = \Istar\Fefiles\Hooks\DataHandler::class;
```

Comment: oh, Can you type code how it will be look in my case, please)

Comment: You are cool man! Thank, thank, thank! Great thank! It working)

Comment: How I can know which fields was updated ? it has historyRecords - protected, I can't get value. I need get old and new value for exactly field. I try it using $parentObject

Comment: As far as I remember, the `$fields` array of `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations` should contain all the fields that have been updated.

Comment: I tried it. It only return follow array

Array
(
    [t3ver_stage] => 0
)

And it does't contain information which I need (

Comment: It should. When I add the following to `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations`: 
`\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($fields);` I get the list of all the fields, that have been changed. Note: it will not contain unchanged fields.

Comment: Can you type all code please ? I can't understand how to use it ? Can I get old value and new value using it ?

Comment: `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations` is a hook for *after* database operations have been completed. There is no way to get the old value in that hook. If you want to know what other hooks there are, then your best bet is to [study the source code](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7-1/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L1328). I don't really have any intention to code it out for you though.